# Where can I find a book that enlists, categorize and discuss the importance of parts of speech?

Tags: reference-request

I've been reading my Portuguese high-school book searching for some classification and hierarchization of [parts of speech](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parts_of_speech). My book brings me such features in a chapter dedicated to morphology, first I thought I needed to find about [morphology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphology_%28linguistics%29), but the given Wikipedia article says that morphology has way more features than parts of speech and I'm specifically interested in parts of speech.

Comment: It really depends on what you mean by "part of speech". There are several approaches, and a long history. And no agreement at all, except that it's a complicated topic.

Comment: I have found [this](http://email.eva.mpg.de/~haspelmt/2001wcl.pdf). It naively describes some classes. Anyway, I'd like to get introduced into this topic.

Comment: Probably [McCawley 1998](http://press.uchicago.edu/ucp/books/book/chicago/S/bo3613599.html), then, since syntactic categories (the technical name) are a principal focus of the book, along with English syntax. However, be aware that different languages have different sets of syntactic categories, and different uses for them. There are a **lot** of different ways to organize them.

Comment: @jlawler Can you add a little more on these different ways? Any recommendation?

Comment: [Read Donatus](http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/don.html), then update from Latin[ca 350] to English[2014]?

Comment: Or have a look at Schachter and Shopen 2007 'Parts of speech systems', [here](http://elchacocomoarealinguistica.wikispaces.com/file/view/Shopen,+T.+2007.+Language+Typology+Vol.+1.pdf)

Comment: @jlawler I thought you were trolling me.

Comment: @PristineKavalostka: That's all right; think nothing of it. I'm not responsible for what you think of me, and vice versa.